# psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal ... DETAIL: Unexpected array element

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm newbie with python django. And I try to create a Multi choices Test website.
I'm a Vietnamese so my questions is in Vietnamese.

I got an issues when I try to insert an object Answers into database.

My error:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: malformed array literal: "{"A": "C\u01a1m", "B": "ch\u00e1o"}"
LINE 1: ...answer", "level") VALUES ('Hôm nay ăn gì', '', 1, '{"A": "C\...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
```

My `POST` request:

```
{
    "title": "Hôm năy ăn gì",
    "category": 3,
    "choices": {
        "A": "Cơm",
        "B": "cháo"
    },
    "answer": "A"
}
```

Here is my code in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
 
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # choices = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True)))
    choices = models.JSONField(null=False, blank=False)
    answer = models.TextField(null=False,blank=False)
    level = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In `views.py`:

```
from django.db.models import query
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import viewsets
from app.models import User, Category, Question
from app.serializers import UserSerializer, QuestionSerializer,  CategorySerializer

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()

class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
```

In `serializers.py`:

```
from django.contrib.postgres import fields
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import User, Question, Category

class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description']

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # category = CategorySerializer(read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id', 'description', 'category', 'choices', 'answer', 'level']
```

Any solution for me to insert an Vietnamese JSON Object into database. Or Can I use ArrayField instead of JSONField? If yes, can you give me an example?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like `Question` model `choices` field has not been changed from an `array` to `json` field in the database. So what your are seeing is:

```
select '{"A": "C\u01a1m", "B": "ch\u00e1o"}'::varchar[];
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{"A": "C\u01a1m", "B": "ch\u00e1o"}"
LINE 1: select '{"A": "C\u01a1m", "B": "ch\u00e1o"}'::varchar[];
```

instead of:

```
select '{"A": "C\u01a1m", "B": "ch\u00e1o"}'::jsonb;
           jsonb           
---------------------------
 {"A": "Cơm", "B": "cháo"}
```

In `psql` look at the question table and see what the field actually is?

Comment: How can I fix it? Can you give me a solution?

Comment: Have you verified what the column type is in the database and if so what is it? Run `migrate`?. Hard to say without more information about how you made the change from `ArrayField` to `JSONField` and whether the existing column has data in it?

Comment: I think my column type is jsonb. After I run `migrate` I got this issue `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type text[] to jsonb
LINE 1: ...on" ALTER COLUMN "choices" TYPE jsonb USING "choices"::jsonb`.

Comment: The error says that the current type for the column in the database is a text array(`text[]`). The model has the column as `JSONField` which translates to `jsonb` in the database. Obviously `migrate` can't handle that transition. I never used `migrate` with Django so I am not going to be of any help there. I would create a new question asking how to migrate an `text[]` field to a `jsonb` one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField


class Question(models.Model):
    
    choices = JSONField()
```